# Google Analytics Plus in Fooman using GTM not working

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics, ecommerce-tracking, google-tag-manager

How to configure the Google Analytics Plus in **magento 1.9.2.1**?

I'm uisng GTM to implement the Google Analytics code but it seem it doesn't track the E commerce Overview.

Answer (score 0):

The GTM functionality in Google Analytics Plus is confined to

1. displaying the tag manager snippet that you copy and paste into the
   back-end on every page
2. sending tracking information for each of the checkout steps and
3. tracking conversions see [here](https://github.com/fooman/googleanalyticsplus/blob/v0.17.0/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/fooman/googleanalyticsplus/tagmanager.phtml#L12)

For functionality beyond this you would need to seek a different solution and/or I am very open to accepting pull requests for it.

Comment: Thank you so much Fooman. Can I ask where should I paste the tracking conversion code? When I view source mypage it seems data layer has commented out  `<script>
      /* <![CDATA[ */
        dataLayer = [];
        /* ]]> */
    </script>`

Comment: It also doesn't track information from each checkout steps.